# Create a time object from minutes

Tags: python

I am trying to create a time object to save to my database. Here is what I have so far:

```
>>> minutes=137
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.time(minute=minutes)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: minute must be in 0..59
```

How would I create a time object with more than 59 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datetime.time()` objects model a *time of day*, not a *duration*. Unless you want your 137 minutes to be interpreted as 137 minutes *after midnight*, you should not be using `datetime.time()` objects.

Use [`datetime.timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) for durations:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> minutes = 137
>>> datetime.timedelta(minutes=minutes)
datetime.timedelta(0, 8220)
```

The `timedelta` object tracks time durations in days and seconds.

If you *did* mean for the time to be interpreted as 2:17am you'll need to calculate the hours and remainder:

```
>>> hour, minute = divmod(minutes, 60)
>>> datetime.time(hour, minute)
datetime.time(2, 17)
```